# Procura em String

Tags: java, string

Tenho uma String de tamanho dinâmico e preciso procurar o cerquilha "#" todos os caracteres até o espaço em branco seguinte.

Já tentei utilizar split, porém sem sucesso.

```
String texto = "oi tudo bem como vai #01?";
String[] t ;
t = texto.split(texto);
```

Comment: Você quer capturar o texto `#01?`?

Comment: Tem certeza que você só quer encontrar? Pergunto porque se você quer criar um mecanismo de substituição de texto para colocar em telas, relatórios, etc., seria melhor não reinventar a roda, pois existem diversos e excelentes mecanismos para isso.

Comment: voce precisa utilizar regex a documentação é bem simples https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ e nesse site tem otimos tutoriais e exemplos [http://www.regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Um exemplo de como separar trechos que comecem com `#` e vão até encontrar um espaço em branco:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String texto = "oi tudo bem como vai #1234a #sdf #$%¨#@)~";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#\\S+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(texto);
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> #1234a
>   #sdf
>   #$%¨#@)~

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/1Q0DEh)

Answer (score 5):

Você pode tentar com regex

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "[#]\\w*\\d*\\W\\s*";
final String string = "oi tudo bem como vai #01?";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/gIxLEB)

Comment: Isso realmente funciona? [Testei e não mostrou nada](https://repl.it/HIuz/3).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
String cantadaHorrivel = "oi tudo bem como vai #01?";
String[] primeiroSplit = cantadaHorrivel.split("#");
String[] segundoSplit = primeiroSplit[1].split(" ");
String texto = segundoSplit[0];
```

Isso falhará caso o input original não tenha cerquilha, então não esqueça de tratar isso também.

Comment: Você podia pelo menos verificar `primeiroSplit.length()` para tratar o caso comum; melhor ainda seria criar uma `List<String>` para conter as instâncias dos termos introduzidos por cerquilha. Não custa mais que umas três linhas a mais...